# HA *slave* node not syncing (1 of 2 nodes only) +neo4j

Tags: neo4j

**Neo4j Version:** 3.2.1
**Operating System:** CentOs 7
**API:** Neo4J

Hi there I am having a weird issue where one of the slave nodes is not syncing to the master. I included the logs (the problem node is n2) and configuration file.

--removed links--

Comment: I'd suggest making your google drive documents public. Currently people can only access them with a request.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to set a non default value to 
ha.pull_interval